# How to use a public variable in .fla file using AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a problem with my public variables in AS3.
I defined a class named Variables.as in the folder com/variables. There is a class named Variables. I have defined 3 Boolean variables in my class and I want to use them in different scene of my main .fla file.
But every time that I want to use them, I will get Access undefined Property error.
Can you please help me on that?

.as file:

```
package  com.variables{

public class Variabels {

    public var tutPage:Boolean = false;
    public var praPage:Boolean = false;
    public var evaPage:Boolean = false;
    public function Variabels() {
    }
}
```

}

.fla file

```
import com.variables.*;
trace(tutPage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:
We need to Define our variables as public static because static variables contain values ​​that apply to the entire class and not to a particular instance.

.as file:

```
package  com.variables{

public class Variabels {

    public static var tutPage:Boolean = false;
    public static var praPage:Boolean = false;
    public static var evaPage:Boolean = false;
    public function Variabels() {

    }
  } 
}
```

.fla file

```
import com.variables.*;
trace(Variabels.tutPage);
```

Comment: consider making your answer more useful by explaining what and why you use the `static`

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis please refer to the adobe help website "http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f31.html". You can find complete explanation there.

Comment: Sorry, let me clearer.  I'm fully aware of what static is and how it's used, but future visitors with a similar issue as you will likely not and simply saying "this is the answer" is not always that helpful.  Good answers should have an **explanation** as to why that particular code is the solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are a bad practice.

You defined variables as members of a class. You can only access them through an instance of the class. You have to instantiate the class, the resulting object will have the variables.

Example:

```
import com.variables.Variabels;

var globalVars:Variabels = new Variabels(); //instantiate the class

trace(globalVars.tutPage);
```

*note that you are spelling variables incorrectly in your class name*

Comment: It will be more helpful if you added an explanation to your claim that global variables are a bad practice (though I do agree).